# How to call a UDF from a JSON file in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a chatbot project which fetches "delivery status" information from a database. I've defined a function (lets call it `db_info`) which will connect to my DB and then get the results.

I have [a .json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf5rM.png) which has different intents like "Greeting", "Status Check", "Closing" etc. The way the application works is - whenever the user types in something, the text is classified into an intent. For ex: when the user types "Hi" the application recognizes it is from the intent "Greeting" and then gives out one of the responses I hard coded in the .json file.

However, for the "Status Check" intent I don't want the application to give out some hard coded response from .json file. Instead, I'd like it to call the `db_info` function when the intent "Status Check" is identified.

I'm aware that a function map (dictionary) can be created in .py file and then its value can be called in the json file. But I'm not sure how this is done exactly.

```py
def db_info(): --> lives in .py file
   # connect to postgres and get some information

if intent == 'greetings':
   # pick random statement from "responses" of tag "greeting" from json file

if intent == 'status_check':
   # go to "responses" under tag "status_check" and run the func mentioned there
   def db_info():
       # instead of picking up a random statement from "response" this func needs to be called
```

My json file:

```
{"tag": "greetings",
 "pattern": ["Hi", "How are you", "Hey", "Hello", "Good Day"],
 "responses": ["Hello!", "Hey there", "Hi, how can I help you today?"]
},
{"tag": "status_check",
 "pattern": ["Where's my shipment", "Track my shipment"],
 "responses": ["GetDBInfo function"]
}
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. Is there a way to call the db_info function from json file? For example: 
"tag": "status_check",
"pattern": "Track my shipment",
"responses": [run db_info function]

Comment: What do you mean from the json file? json is not code, it's just data. You parse that with Python code... You call the function through Python

Comment: You can modify the json to have another field `"func"` which will just be `"print"` for all intents and for status check it will be `db_info`

Comment: At the moment I have my JSON like this:
{"tag": "status_check",
"pattern": ["check my shipment", "track my shipment", "status of shipment"],
"responses": [generally contains the response I want application to give back to user.. in this case db_info]
}

Comment: Please don't use comments for that. [edit] the question with an example of your json, just so I have something to work with to show you what I had in mind

Comment: Added sample json to my question.

Comment: I'll repeat what other's have said: we need a [mcve] that will actually run. Your current code example has multiple run time errors. Instead of explaining what the code does in a comment, put some actual code.

Comment: Universal Disk Format?

Comment: @user3840170, User Defined Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your json to match the following parsing process:

- find the intent the pattern matches
- get a response
- pass it as an argument to the function of that intent

This means that you will add a `"function"` field to the json and call it when you parse. All intents will simply have it as `"print"` (or whatever other default operation you're doing) and the `"Status_Check"` intent will have its own special function. Then, just map the names to actual function objects that you can call.

So the json can look like this:

```json
[{"tag": "greetings",
  "pattern": ["Hi", "How are you", "Hey", "Hello", "Good Day"],
  "function": "print",
  "responses": ["Hello!", "Hey there", "Hi, how can I help you today?"]
 },
  {"tag": "status_check",
    "pattern": ["Where's my shipment", "Track my shipment"],
    "function": "GetDBInfo",
    "responses": [""]
  }]
```

And to parse it:

```py
import json
import random

def db_info(useless_arg):
    print("from func")

func_mapping = {"print": print,
                "GetDBInfo": db_info}

with open("test.json") as file:
    intents = json.load(file)

text = input("input: ")

for intent in intents:
    if text in intent["pattern"]:
        function = intent["function"]
        arg = random.choice(intent["responses"])
        func_mapping[function](arg)
```

An example run:

```
input: Where's my shipment
from func

input: Hi
Hello!
```